# Adding buttons to panel dynamically

Tags: button, extjs4, panel

ExtJS 4

How to add a button to a panel (dynamically) as if in the buttons property?
In ExtJS 3, we have `panel.addButton()` but didn't find any such function in ExtJS 4. I tried `panel.addDocked()` too but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    var p = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        renderTo: document.body,
        title: 'A Panel',
        buttons: [{
            text: 'B1'
        }]
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        p.down('toolbar').add({
            text: 'B2'
        });
    }, 1000);

});
```

Comment: I want to have the buttons only in the buttons configuration of the mainpanel only. I have many child panels with toolbar and the buttons were getting appended there.

Later, I used this query.  
tab.down('>toolbar[dock="bottom"]').add(tab.buttons);
  to get the bottom bar

Now its retreiving both buttons and bbar. How can I distinguish between the two?

Comment: It also works on Window. `win.down('toolbar').add({...})`. Thanks.

Comment: `Window` is a subclass of `Panel`.